# Centrar las td de html en una tabla

Tags: javascript, css, html5

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        tr{
            text-align: center;
            background-color: red;
        }
        td{
            padding: 50px;
            border: 1px black;
        }
        table{
            border: 5px solid green;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<table >
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var num = prompt("Introduce el numero: ")*1;
        if (isNaN(num)==false && num % 2 != 0) {
            for(var i=1; i<=num;i+=2){
                document.write('<tr>');
                for(var x = i; x>=1 ;x--){

                    document.write('<td>');

                    document.write('</td>');        
                }
                document.write('</tr>');
            }
        }else{
            document.write("Numero incorrecto!")
        }
//      for (var i = num; i > 0; i-=2) {
    </script>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

De hecho, lo que estoy intendando hacer es una piramide con numeros impares. Donde la entrada seria numeros impares y éste va dibujando piramide. Lo que quiero hacer es centrar todos los TD. De tal forma que quede una pirámide. Gracias...Aunque dudo que el ejercicio lo tenga bien hecho...

Comment: No es la mejor idea hacer eso con una tabla. Si aún así quieres hacerlo con una tabla ponle `display: inline-block` a los `td`

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: se necesitaria una imagen del resultado esperado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que la mejor alternativa que tienes es crear una tabla con las siguientes proporciones:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cada vez que ingreses 1 numero se le agregue un `<td>` en blanco adelante, excepto en el ultimo numero de ese piso, después de el siguiente nivel agregas **n** `<td>` al inicio para ir formando la pirámide y al final puedes quitar los bordes a las celdas para que se vean como en la imagen o solo ponerle bordes a las celdas que contengan números.

Espero que esto te pueda ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que buscas es centrar el contenido de una etiqueta **td**, puedes acceder a la propiedad **style** de la etiqueta y aplicar la propiedad **text-align** y su valor de centrado:

```
<table>
  <tr><td style="text-align: center;"> Valor </td></tr>
</table>
```